# Is there any method I can modify the "IP" address without removing the docker container?

Tags: docker

I use `docker run` command to create and run a container:

```
docker run -p 10.10.220.52:80:8080 ubuntu bash
```

But suddenly, I find I use the wrong `IP` address. Is there any method I can modify the `IP` address without killing it and create a new one?